# Display Text when Delete button is clicked in GridView

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

I have a Gridview., usually, when the delete command button is clicked then the row will be deleted., But what should I do if I want a alert message like "Are you sure......." to be displayed.....
Any Ideas please

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/webforms/GridViewConfirmDelete.aspx

Answer (score 1):

You can do this easily via a template column:

```
<asp:TemplateField ShowHeader="False">
     <ItemTemplate> 
    <asp:LinkButton ID="btnDelete" runat="server" CausesValidation="False" CommandName="Delete"
                        OnClientClick='return confirm("Are you sure you want to delete?");'
                       Text="Delete" />
</ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

Comment: Thanks for a quick response. Ya I knw so can't we do it with Gridview Buttons???????

Comment: you have to make that button as template field

Answer (score 1):

Just before doing the delation (the way you do) use messageBox with DialogResult object. If the user agrees with delation do the delation, if not, return:

```
 if (DialogResult.Yes == MessageBox.Show("You want to delate the row?", "Question", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Question))
        {
            //delete the row!
        }
```

You dont actually do anything if he selects No. The code will not execute anything.

Comment: I think the question is for ASP.NET, not Windows Forms